# How to set an environment variable programmatically in TeamCity using Python

Tags: python, teamcity

Tested locally with python, working fine.

Trying to set the `env.variable` in TeamCity as my local variable `decomaccountalias` to use in future buildstep

my code is

```
print(f"##teamcity[setParameter name='env.DECOM_ACCOUNT_ALIAS' value ='{decomaccountalias}']")
```

so it looks like it's working as teamcity returns

```
##teamcity[setParameter name='env.DECOM_ACCOUNT_ALIAS' value ='['variable']
```

however then below gives the following error

> error while parsing TeamCity service message: value should start with "'". Valid service message has a form of "##teamcity[messageName name1='escaped_value' etc etc

Answer (score 0):

If your code

```
print(f"##teamcity[ ... value ='{decomaccountalias}']")
```

writes

```
##teamcity[... value ='['variable']
```

then presumably the value of `decomaccountalias` is `['variable`?

---

In [the documentation for `setParameter`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/service-messages.html#set-parameter) its example is:

```
##teamcity[setParameter name='ddd' value='fff']
```

where the value (`fff` in the example) is escaped.

[The documentation for Escaped Values](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/service-messages.html#Escaped+Values) says:

> For escaped values, TeamCity uses a vertical bar `|` as an escape character. To have certain special characters properly interpreted by the TeamCity server, they must be preceded by a vertical bar. For example, the following message:
>
> ```
> ##teamcity[testStarted name='foo|'s test']
> ```
>
> will be displayed in TeamCity as `foo's test`.

---

You should escape the special characters in `decomaccountalias`, e.g. using `replace`:

```
escapeddecomaccountalias = decomaccountalias.replace("'", "|'").replace("[", "|[").replace("]", "|]")
print(f"##teamcity[setParameter name='env.DECOM_ACCOUNT_ALIAS' value ='{escapeddecomaccountalias}']")
```

Disclaimer: other special characters which would need to be replaced include `\n`, `\r`, `|`, and various Unicode symbols - I've not included code to do this in my answer as I'm not that familiar with Python. Likewise, there are probably better ways of doing the replace...